# Remove element when document click - but still fire click event for the element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry I am having trouble trying to put this into words and struggled with the title. I am using jQuery to remove an element in certain conditions - and I also am looking out for clicks on this element. It seems that it is being removed before the click event fires and I have tried all sorts of things to get it to work well.

http://jsfiddle.net/Yr54c/

If you comment out the first #icon.remove() on that fiddle it all works fine but what I want is for the little icon to disappear if someone clicks off of it. I hope I've made sense! Please see the fiddle for a demo.

Basically what should happen is when a word is selected between 2-25 characters an icon (div) appears next to it. That icon remains until:

1. It is clicked on - and the footer appears.
2. There is a click somewhere else on the page.

Bearing in mind that people may drag to select words, or double click!
I have only jQuery **1.4.4** to work with too!

```
selectionchange.start();

document.addEventListener('selectionchange', function (event) {
    var sel = this.getSelection();

    if (sel.toString().length > 1 && sel.toString().length < 25) {
        $("#icon").remove();
        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0)
        var startNode = range.startContainer,
            startOffset = range.startOffset;
        if (range.endOffset > range.startOffset) {
            startNode = range.endContainer;
            startOffset = range.endOffset;
        }
        var boundaryRange = range.cloneRange();
        boundaryRange.collapse(false);
        boundaryRange.insertNode($('<div id="icon" data="' + sel + '"></div>')[0]);
        boundaryRange.setStart(startNode, startOffset);
        boundaryRange.collapse(true);
    }

});

$("#icon").live("touchend click", function(e) {
    $("#footer").remove();
    $("body").append("<div id='footer'><div id='footer-inner'><p></p></div></div>");
    $("#icon").remove();
    $("#footer-inner p").html('<div id="footer-close">Close this bar</div>');
});
```

Comment: ~4 year old version of jQuery. Wonder how many people will answer to use `on`? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `selectionchange` event on document currently fires first and delete the `#icon` before click event on it is fired. Do not remove your icon on `selectionchange` but rather do it on a click event outside the `#icon` element. For example, replace your click listener on `#icon` by:

```
$(document).bind("click", function (e) {
    if(e.target.id=="icon")
    {
       $("#footer").remove();
       $("body").append("<div id='footer'><div id='footer-inner'><p></p></div></div>");
       $("#footer-inner p").html('<div id="footer-close">Close this bar</div>');
    }
    $("#icon").remove();
});
```

Live example at http://jsfiddle.net/Yr54c/3/

Comment: I was trying something similar but the problem with this is that if you double click to select, or select by dragging and release the mouse when you are not OVER the element, it will disappear, prematurely :(

Comment: Sorry i miss those points. Is this update closer to your needs ? : http://jsfiddle.net/Yr54c/5/ (I am not sure to well understand the second point)

Answer (score 0):

The event binding on the #icon is called before the element creation on the DOM.
So you need to call that method after this line in your code:

```
boundaryRange.insertNode($('<div id="icon" data="' + sel + '"></div>')[0]);
bindEvent();  // something like this


function bindEvent(){
    $("#icon").live("touchend click", function(e) {
        $("#footer").remove();
        $("body").append("<div id='footer'><div id='footer-inner'><p></p></div></div>");
        $("#icon").remove();
        $("#footer-inner p").html('<div id="footer-close">Close this bar</div>');
    });
}
```

Comment: according to documentation the `live()` method "Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future". No problem if the element already exists or not with such a method.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is that you're creating a new icon element every time the "selectionchange" event is fired (by calling $("#icon").remove() and then adding a new one), but you're only binding the click handler function once, when the code is first run. This is because the click and touchend binding happens outside of the selectionchange handler.

To solve this problem, you should either bind a new touch and click handler function to the new icon element every time you create one, or (this is better practice, IMO) bind the click handler function to the element which contains the #icon, by using

```
$(".cool").on("click", "#icon", (handler));
```

Comment: on is not going to help with jQuery 1.4.4! ;)